# Angular PWA and NGRX.. fetch data if offline

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, ngrx

I would like to ask if there is a way where i could still retrieve data using ngrx even if the angular app is down due to network or no internet.
the idea is like.. if no internet then pull default data that have been saved in the store so far.

Comment: Yes, PWA is a set of features which you can use to achieve something like, among others, but the questions still broad. Try to implement something and change the question to be more specific. Some further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlexBiro yeah I'm using PWA.. so i have a list of person. if the site is offline i should be able to view the list still.. and once the internet has came back up.. then it should auto reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a minimalistic PWA, you need to do following:

First you register the service worker with:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js').then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
      }, function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
      });
    });
  }
```

First you check if its even available in your browser. If it is, then you need to pass the path to your service worker. In this example its `/serviceworker.js`.

Remember: Registration wont work if you are using HTTP or the file system `C://` you need to use either HTTPS or with localhost it should work too.

Now the service worker part. With this exmaple you will cache every page you visit, and if you turn off your network it should still work.

```
//serviceworker.js

var CACHE_NAME = "my_cache_v1";

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
          // Cache hit - return response
          if (response) {
            return response;
          }
  
          return fetch(event.request).then(
            function(response) {
              // Check if we received a valid response
              if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                return response;
              }
  
              // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
              // and because we want the browser to consume the response
              // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
              // to clone it so we have two streams.
              var responseToCache = response.clone();
  
              caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                  cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                });
  
              return response;
            }
          );
        })
      );
  });
```

You can do more with PWA. You can ask the user to install your app, or you can subscribe user to Push notifications. Actually i work on a small library that should simplify that for you you can check it out here: (still under development)

https://github.com/ilijanovic/serviceHelper

https://www.npmjs.com/package/servicehelper

To make it installable you would need to include a manifest to your site with the essential properties.

Comment: I would like to understand this state management in angular or any UI framework.. CQRS on what i know in backend it is.. saving to database then after saving then putting it to somewhere for later retrieval so that when we pull data we can just pull from cache. is the same principle applied in this state management?

Comment: with PWA all happens on the client side. In this example the service worker is enabled and is between the client and the "internet". So if you do a request, it first goes through the service worker. It checks if you already did that request and returns to you out of the cache storage, if not, it will do a network request and that response is gonna be cached so next time it loads out of the cache. its also called cache first because you first take a look into the cache before you make a network request. there are other strategies like making a request to the network FIRST and only access

Comment: @JaysonGonzaga the cache if you are offline.

Comment: so the cached data came from ngrx?what do you call these strategies? are they related to ngrx or any state management frameworks? apology i'm just a beginner in this part of UI development

Comment: PWA, service-workers are not related to any, farmeworks. they can be used with angular, vue.js , react, multi page sites, etc.